# How to extract a numeric id from a string using groovy in SOAP UI

Tags: groovy, soapui

One of the service is returning a field with a value like this one below , I want to extract the number '2734427' from the below string using Groovy in SOAP UI

`[[https%3a%2f%2fthis.is.a.sample.link%2fproduct-data-v1%2f/jobs/2734427]]`

I have used the below lines of codes - which works , but it looks a bit hacky .Was wondering if anyone could suggest a better option.

```
//Get the value of the Job Id Link 
def gtm2joblink = "[[https%3a%2f%2fthis.is.a.sample.link%2fproduct-data-v1%2f/jobs/2734427]]"
// split jobid full link for extracting the actual id  
def sub1 = { it.split("jobs/")[1] }
def jobidwithbrackets = sub1(gtm2joblink)
// split jobid full link for extracting the actual id  
def sub2 = { it.split("]]")[0] }
def jobid = sub2(jobidwithbracket)


log.info gtm2joblink
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a regular expression. If the job ID always follows `/jobs`, and is always numeric, and there are always double brackets `]]` at the end, then the following will extract the ID:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher 

//Get the value of the Job Id Link 
def gtm2joblink = "[[https%3a%2f%2fthis.is.a.sample.link%2fproduct-data-v1%2f/jobs/2734427]]"

Matcher regexMatcher = gtm2joblink =~ /(?ix).*\\/jobs\\/([0-9]*)]]/
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String jobId = regexMatcher.group(1);
    log.info(jobId)
} else  {
    log.info('No job ID found')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @craigcaulfield